# Acesso a formulário externo com recaptcha

Tags: formulário, recaptcha

Olá!
Estou fazendo uma aplicação na área de orçamento participativo, gostaria de saber qual a melhor solução (se houver) para conectar a uma página externa web, preencher um formulário, permitir ao usuário resolver o recaptcha da página externa e recuperar os dados de resposta da página externa.
Página externa:
http://apps.tse.jus.br/saae/consultaLocalVotacaoNome.do

Eu vi algumas soluções aqui para receber os dados de cpf e cnpj da receita federal, porém nesses casos usa o captcha de "imagem", essa página traz o recaptcha novo "check box".

Tentei carregar essa página dentro na minha pagina em um iframe mais dai não consigo nem recuperar o html do iframe por ser uma questão de domínio cruzado.

Desde já obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: Teria como fazer esta mesma aplicação com o este site https://www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br/SimplesNacional/controleAcesso/Autentica.aspx?id=60 Preciso acesso esta pagina com os dados que vem do banco de dados

Comment: Você conseguiu resolver seu problema? por coincidência estou fazendo um projeto semelhante de procura de CPF por exemplo, e a maioria usa o recaptcha, enche o saco...

Answer (score 0):

Não é possível resolver o CAPTCHA em outra aplicação, que não a página porque uma das informações enviadas a página que recebe o action, é um token fornecido pelo Google. Se possível use Iframe. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: O captcha antigo (aquele que gera uma imagem com caracteres) é usado no site da receita, achei uma solução em PHP para ele:
https://github.com/Massa191/Consultas_CNPJ_CPF_Receita_Federal

A diferença para o meu exemplo é que nele usa aquele recaptcha "chekbox".

O iframe até me resolveria, o problema que encontrei nele é que não consigo obter os dados da página após o redirecionamento do formulário pela questão de domínio cruzado.

Comment: se você conseguir resolver o problema do captcha, você pode usar ajax pra passar e receber o resto dos valores, não?

Comment: Acredito que sim, mais ainda não consegui uma solução para esse recaptcha "novo" que usa um "check box".